# Create model inside another model view in Yii2

Tags: php, html, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

I want to add a pop up inside `video/view.php`(similar to youtube when you watch a video), and when you click on "Add to Playlist" to display `playlist/create.php`and add a playlist. The problem is that "playlist" is outside the scope of "video" and it doesnt detect what `$this` is or anything really.

Is there a way to do this, using the incorporated create action inside playlist?

I am using a `video/_buttons.php` to do the buttons inside `video/view.php`

_buttons.php which have like,dislike and "add to playlist" button

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Url;
?>
<a href="<?php echo Url::to(['/video/like', 'id' => $model->video_id]) ?>"
   class="btn btn-sm <?php echo $model->isLikedBy(Yii::$app->user->id) ? 'btn-outline-primary': 'btn-outline-secondary' ?>"
   data-method="post" data-pjax="1">
    <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i> <?php echo $model->getLikes()->count() ?>
</a>

<a href="<?php echo Url::to(['/video/dislike', 'id' => $model->video_id]) ?>"
   class="btn btn-sm <?php echo $model->isDislikedBy(Yii::$app->user->id) ? 'btn-outline-primary': 'btn-outline-secondary' ?>"
   data-method="post" data-pjax="1">
    <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i> <?php echo $model->getDislikes()->count() ?>
</a>

<a class="btn btn-sm <?php echo 'btn-outline-secondary' ?>"
   id="myBtn">Add to Playlist</a>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>Here i want to create a playlist item</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The way the buttons are implemented in `video/view.php`

```
            <div>
            <?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin() ?>
            <?php echo $this->render('_buttons', [
                'model' => $model
            ]) ?>
            <?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end() ?>
        </div>
```

And the action "create" in `playlist/create`

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
$this->title = 'Create Playlist';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Playlists', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="playlist-create">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?= $this->render('_form', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]) ?>
</div>
```

Any help is usefull!

Comment: Here is a good solution similar to the problem you have: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106325/yii2-form-in-modal-window

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `playlist/create.php` adding a slash to it, so it will be like this: `/playlist/create.php`.

This is equivalent to saying that you should search a view starting by the root path of the `views` folder.